# Как добавить индикатор количества к меню

Tags: css, вёрстка, веб-дизайн

У меня есть меню которое которое состоит из табов. Табы это простые текстовые кнопки. Я бы хотел добавить индикаторы к каждой кнопке, чтобы если пользователь что то выбрал в табе отображалось количество выбранных элементов в кнопке соответствующего раздела. Пример индикатора вы можете найти снизу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только у меня текстовые кнопки, а не иконки.
Не смог найти решения проблемы. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример](https://codepen.io/Gortyser/pen/zELpLG)

```
<style>
.icon {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.icon:after {
  content:'1';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -10px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
}
</style>
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart icon"></i>
```

Например, как-то так. Это в том случае, если проблема только в плашке с количеством элементов, а не в скрипте, который считал бы эти элементы.
P.S. Поменяйте font-size на какое-нибудь еще значение, а то иконки как-то багаются.

Comment: Большое спасибо @Sinnabon за помощь, сохранили мне час времени ;) Попробую подобрать более подходящий для меня размер